# Display all subfolders of folder in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to display my uploaded content in my view page.

I have uploaded some files to my assets folder. In this the applicant (here) has an id, and uploading documents also have an id. During uploading these document ids are inserted in db with commas.

The uploaded path is `./assets/uploads/applicant_id/document_id`.

I want to display the all files from this path. Problem is that when l have uploaded a document, and display only its (last uploaded) document files .

```
       function index() 
{   
    $application_id=$this->session->userdata('application_id');
    $this->load->helper('directory');


    $document_details = $this->home_model->get_document_details(); 
    $$document_ids = $this->home_model->get_evidence_ids($application_id); 
    $$document_id= $evidence_ids->applicant_evidence_id;   
    $document= explode(',',$evidence_id);
    for($i=0; $i < count($evidence); $i++)
    {
        $uploaded_files = array();
        $uploaded_files = directory_map('./application/assets/uploads/'.$application_id.'/'.$document_id[$i]);
    }       

    $data=array(
    'document'=>$document,
    'document_details'=>$document_details,
    'page_name'=>'Home',
    'dashboard_index'=>1,
    'uploaded_files' =>$uploaded_files,
    'application_id'=>$application_id, 
    'head_extra'=>'<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.base_url().'application/assets/css/home.css"> ',
    'footer_extra'=>'',
    );    
    $this->load->view('header',$data);
    $this->load->view('index',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer',$data); 
}
function do_upload()
{    
    $evidence_id = $_POST['document_id'];    
    $application_id=$this->session->userdata('application_id');
    $this->load->library('upload');

    $files = $_FILES;
    $cpt = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
    {           
        $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $files['userfile']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['userfile']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['userfile']['size'][$i];    

        $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options($document_id,$application_id));
        $this->upload->do_upload();
    }
    $evidence = $this->home_model->insert_evidence($application_id,$document_id);
    $success_message = "Document Uploaded.";
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success_message',$success_message);
    redirect(base_url().'home','refresh');
}
private function set_upload_options($document_id,$application_id)
{   

    if(!is_dir('./application/assets/uploads/'.$application_id.'/'.$document_id)) 
    {
        mkdir('./application/assets/uploads/'.$application_id.'/'.$document_id, 0777, TRUE);

    }
    $config = array();
    $config['upload_path'] = './application/assets/uploads/'.$application_id.'/'.$document_id;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|bmp|jpeg|gif|vnd.ms-excel|vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet|csv|pdf';
    $config['max_size']      = '0';
    $config['overwrite']     = FALSE;

    return $config;
}
```

**view**

```
  <div class="portal-body">                             
                <?php $file_count = count($uploaded_files);    
                    for($i=0;$i<$file_count;$i++)
                    { ?>
                    <p><?php echo $uploaded_files[$i]; ?></p>   
                    <?php } ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: you want to show all image of application_id or only its sub folders

Answer (score 0):

First get the images from database
For ex.

```
$images = image1,image2,image3;
$newImages = explode(',',$images);
```

Now use foreach loop

```
    foreach($newImages as $img)
    {
   //check for file type
                $name = $img; 
                    $info = new SplFileInfo($name);
                    $extension =  $info->getExtension();
                    //echo $extension;

    if($extension  == "jpg" || $extension  == "png" || $extension  == "gif" || $extension  == "jpeg") {
      <img src="<?php echo base_url('your file location/.$img');?>">;
    }else{

    show your file here
    }
    }
```

For more read this tutorial

http://w3code.in/2015/09/upload-file-using-codeigniter/

Comment: i have already exploded the ids from database. now i want to display all files belongs to that id

Comment: Use foreach loop  I have given in answer

Comment: its only about images , i have files other than images

Comment: Updated answerr check again